# How to load an RData file with QlikView?

Tags: r, qlikview

Is anybody aware of loading a RData file with QlikView? The reason why I would like to do this that I have a large dataset in R that I would like to analyse interactively with QlikView. Moreover, it takes very long to store the data with the `write.csv` function in R.

Comment: Have you come across [this](http://community.qlikview.com/docs/DOC-2975) page in your searches? It talks about Qlikview/R integration. Not sure if it specifically address reading in RData files, but could be useful nonetheless.

Comment: Also, [this](http://community.qlikview.com/thread/86455) may useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write it as a text file of some sort, then it is trivial to load it into Qlikview. For SAS files you could have SAS act as an sql server and use Qlikview, but it does not seem R can act as a server

Comment: Yes it would indeed be nice if you connect to R as an SQL server. Via a query statement you could select data or execute a stored procedure (R script). Anyway, that is not the case... (at least not yet).